# Php called from ajax not working on multiple calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using a simple javascript function to call a php script when i click a button or link and to return some data. It works fine until i try to call data from a aleady outputed data via that function. Let show you my script:

```js
$(function() {
$(".article_edit").click(function() {
var article_id = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'article_id='+article_id;  
//$('a#'+article_id).removeClass('liked');
$('#post-body-'+article_id).fadeOut("slow").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
$('a#'+article_id).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "action/article_enable_edit.php",
 data: dataString,
 cache: false,
 success: function(data){
    if (data == 0) {
 alert('Actiunea nu a putut fi realizata!');
 } else {
 $('#post-body-'+article_id).fadeIn("slow").html(data);
 }
 }  
});
return false;
});
});


$(function() {
$(".article_edit_close").click(function() {
var article_id = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'article_id='+article_id;  
//$('a#'+article_id).removeClass('liked');
$('#post-body-'+article_id).fadeOut("slow").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
$('a#'+article_id).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" class="loading" />'); 
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "action/article_show.php",
 data: dataString,
 cache: false,
 success: function(data){
    if (data == 0) {
 alert('Actiunea nu a putut fi realizata!');
 } else {
 $('#post-body-'+article_id).fadeIn("slow").html(data);
 }
 }  
});
return false;
});
});
```

```html
<!--  First button-->
<a class="color-transition article_edit" href="#" id="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>

<!--  When i click it the content will be replaced with another one containing this-->
<!-- output from action/article_enable_edit.php -->
    <a class="color-transition article_edit_save" href="#" id="'.$id.'" ><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>
    <a class="color-transition article_edit_close" href="#" id="'.$id.'" ><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>

<!-- Now, if i click on any link, for example: .article_edit_close, the function will not work.  -->
<!-- i should have an output from action/article_show.php -->
<!-- If i put these oow links on the index.php page, they worked, but that is not what i need.-->
```

Why i can't call a function from a content wich is called by another function? They do not happen at the same time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `click` event of link/button using `.on` for dynamic elements.

So your click event code will look something like this,

```
$('body').on('click','.article_edit_close',function(e){
     // Your code goes here...
});
```

> **.on()** attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(document).on("click",".article_edit",function(){ /* ... */  });
```

instead of

```
$(".article_edit").click();
```